# 'radius' is not a parameter in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, parameters

Using a NuGet library [Accord.net](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Collections_KDTree_1.htm)

Autocomplete shows a parameter:

```
radius:=
```

[image: Autocomplete]

But when I finish the line to look like this:

```
 Dim result = tree.Nearest(tn.Position, radius:=3.1)
```

I get the error:

> BC30272   'radius' is not a parameter of 'Public Overloads Function Nearest(position As Double(), neighbors As Integer) As KDTreeNodeCollection(Of KDTreeNode(Of KDTreeNode(Of Double)))'.

I've never run into this before. What could be the issue?

---

Edit: To answer questions in the comments:
@GSerg asks:

> It should be double, not decimal. Is Dim result = the actual code you
>   are running, or do you in fact have a type declared for result? Does
>   it call the correct overload if you don't provide the parameter name?

double vs decimal:

```
Dim result As KDTreeNodeCollection(Of KDTreeNode(Of Integer)) = tree.Nearest(query, Convert.ToDouble(2.00003))
```

The following does not work either:

```
    Dim query = New Double() {6, 6, 6}
    Dim radius As Double = 2.000014
    Dim result = tree.Nearest(query, radius)
```

I get the function that uses the int32 as the second parameter so the results are limited to the 2 in that case. It should return 20.

Regarding Dim result = ... I have tried it both:

```
    Dim result = tree.Nearest(query, radius)
    'and
    Dim result As KDTreeNodeCollection(Of KDTreeNode(Of Integer)) = tree.Nearest(query, radius)
```

Neither works.

Comment: Apparently you end up calling http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Collections_KDTreeBase_1_Nearest_4.htm instead of http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Collections_KDTreeBase_1_Nearest_1.htm. Do you see the latter overload in your object browser? Does it make a difference if you use `3.1#`?

Comment: The second param takes a `Integer`, just pass a `Integer`, not a double, you dont need the name either. As the error states, theres not a param with that name, its `neighbors`.

Comment: @GSerg that is exactly what seems to be happening. I do see the latter overload in the object browser. It is in the KDTreeBase which is inherited by KDTree. Using 3.1# does not work, nor does Convert.ToDecimal(3.1).

Comment: It should be double, not decimal. Is `Dim result = ` the actual code you are running, or do you in fact have a type declared for `result`? Does it call the correct overload if you don't provide the parameter name?

Comment: @Gserg - I edited my post to include answers to your questions.

Comment: Try creating a new test project, add that package, call that method and see if the same thing happens.  Isolating the issue in a test project is pretty much always one of the first steps when seemingly weird things like this happen.

Comment: Also note that the overload you want returns `List(Of NodeDistance(Of TNode))`, not `KDTreeNodeCollection(Of TNode)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  - good idea. Same behaviour, even if I create a C# app. I also remoted in to my work computer and the results are worse there. On that machine it will not even see KDTree at all. I am beginning to think that this is a package installation issue.

Comment: I have had problems with Xamarin, where the IDE would look into one folder for the source file and the compiler would look in another, so the IDE would claim there is a compile error and underline in red, but it would actually compile fine. That error message you've got, is it from the IDE underlying the line of code, or is it from trying to actually compile?

Comment: It seems like a signature issue. The example from the docs does not call out a type for the variable so it looks to me like it is defaulting to the integer style function. I need to define my variable that is receiving the result as a specific type. When i define the receiving variable the type that the compiler calls for in the hint when I hover then it complains at run time.

Comment: @GSerg I just saw your comment. I will try that when I am back in front of the computer. You may very well be right.